# WebClient set headers

Tags: c#, .net, header, webclient

How I can set a header in the `webClient` class?
I tried:

```
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "image/jpeg";
```

that throws a `WebException`

My code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "image/png");
client.Headers.Set("Content-Length", length);
client.Headers.Add("Slug", name);
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("file", FileContents);

Byte[] data = client.UploadValues(url, nvc);
string res = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
Response.Write(res);
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If the header already exists:

```
client.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
```

if its a new header:

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
```

Also, there is a chance that you are getting an error because you are trying to set the headers too late. Post your exception so we can let you know.

**Update**

<strike>Looks like there are some weird restrictions on the "Content-Type" header with the WebClient class. Look in to using the client.Download methods (DownloadData, DownloadFile, etc...)</strike>

See if using the "UploadFile" method on webclient works rather than doing it manually. It returns the respose body byte[].

If you continue to have issues with the WebClient, try justing using a plain old HttpRequest/HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The Content-Type header can not be changed from its default value for this request.

Comment: does client.Headers.Add update existing headers too ?

Answer (score 17):

It seems you can not set Content-type with WebClient.UploadValues method. You could set Content-type with WebClient.UploadData method

Use something like,

```
Client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
Client.UploadData("http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php", "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes("{\"Data\": \"Test\"}"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the Content-Type if you use the UploadValues method, it must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, see webclient source code 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this syntax: `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`

What's your stack trace? At what point are you setting this? And what version of IIS/OS are you running under?

Comment: What's your stack trace? And at what point are setting headers? Can post some more code?