# How to upload any file on Slack via Slack-App in c#

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

I need help with uploading files to Slack.

I have a Slack-App that is working with my code(below) so far. But all I can do is post messages. I can not attach images to the messages - because I do not understand how to use the so called "methods" and the syntax Slack is "showing" on their API-page.

This creates my "content" and below its just a Stream for reading a file I could upload:

```
    public class PostMessage
    {


        public FormUrlEncodedContent Content(string message, string file)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"token", "xoxp-myToken"},
                { "username", "X"},         
                { "channel", "myChannel"},
                { "as_user", "false"},     
                {"text", message},
                { "content", file},
                { "attachments","[{ \"fallback\":\"dummy\", \"text\":\"this is a waste of time\"}]"}
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            return content;
        }
    }

    public class PostFile
    {
        String path = @"C:\Users\f.held\Desktop\Held-Docs\dagged.jpg";

        public string ReadImageFile()
        {            
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
            long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
            var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(imageData);
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

The client that communicates:

```
public class SlackClient
{
        private readonly Uri _webhookUrl;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient {};

        public SlackClient(Uri webhookUrl)
        {
            _webhookUrl = webhookUrl;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(FormUrlEncodedContent content)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_webhookUrl, content);

            return response;
        }    
     }
}
```

The Main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.WaitAll(IntegrateWithSlackAsync());
}

private static async Task IntegrateWithSlackAsync()
{
    var webhookUrl = new Uri("https://slack.com/api/files.upload");
    var slackClient = new SlackClient(webhookUrl);
    PostMessage PM = new PostMessage();
    PostFile PF = new PostFile();


    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Type a message: ");
        var message = Console.ReadLine();
        var testFile = PF.ReadImageFile();
        FormUrlEncodedContent payload = PM.Content(message, testFile);
        var response = await slackClient.SendMessageAsync(payload);
        var isValid = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "valid" : "invalid";
        Console.WriteLine($"Received {isValid} response.");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        response.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}
}

If somebody has an example on what a upload has to look like. Or even better,

if somebody could really explain the syntax these Slack-Messages have to have.

That would be great! I still do not know where and HOW I should put the so called
*"Accepted content types:   multipart/form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded"* to my upload. I just can not find examples on this...

**Edit:**

What confuses me needlesly is that Slack states they have an extra method called `file.upload` - but we shouldn't use it anymore, we should use just `postMessage`.

But how would I "pack" a file in a message? My syntax always seems to be off. Especially when it comes to "content"...
I just can not figure out what the c#-code has to look like. Where do I declare the aforementioned "content type"?

Another problem is, it always sends my messages through - means I get a 200-response from the server. But it never shows the file (which probably means the syntax is off) Or I get the 200-response but the message never shows in Slack.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your aim is: do you want to attach an image to your message OR do you want to upload a file to Slack?

Comment: Hey Erik,
well I need to be able to do both. But why is there even a difference? Everything is a file, right? I know you posted on my other question that with messages I could only post images. But Slack explicitely states that file uploads are treated as messages now (look here: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2018-05-file-threads-soon-tread ) . Or am I reading this wrong? When I use the SlackRTM it doesn't seem to behave differently when uploading images of any kind or files... so?!

Thanks!

Comment: you are correct. `files.upload` are now creating messages, but there still is a difference. file uploads will include the file only and the file is physically uploaded to Slack. In contrast you can include multiple images in a message, along with text. And those images are not uploaded. You just provide a URL to it.

Comment: Here is a screenshot showing both file upload and message with image attachment: https://i.imgur.com/w5dgw5s.png

Comment: Okay... I know what you mean, but I am talking about uploading files and images on  my physical harddrive, not something that is online anywhere. And I have to stick to my answer that I want to do both :) upload files and messages with files attached. 
I just tested my FileStream, by which I mean I converted it back to an image and wrote it to my harddrive. And it worked, so my fault has to lie somewhere in the "message" I send. Or the Object I actually create and then encode and send... but yet I'm clueless. And I am constantly on this issue - since 8 AM :(

Comment: Hmm.. just to be clear. Slack can not use images from your physical hard drive. You need to either upload it to the Slack Internet cloud via `files.upload` or attach it with a public URL to a message. And you can combine those two: first upload the image to Slack, then use that image in a message with a Slack URL

Comment: Note that you can not embed an image file in a message, only URLs. I added info on how to first upload image to Slack and then use then in a message in my answer.

Comment: I added a working example to my answer.

Comment: Apologizes for removing part of your question text. The reason is that Stack Overflow aims to provide questions that can be helpful for many people. Therefore questions should be as brief as possible, so salutations and personal comments that are not directly related to the question are removed.

Comment: No worries, I just thought it might seem rude to straight go to the problem. But, yeah it actually makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a shorter working example showing how to just upload any file to Slack with C# only. The example will also automatically share the file the given channel.

I have included the logic to convert the API response from JSON, which will always be needed to determine if the API call was successful.

Note: This example requires [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class SlackExample
{
    // classes for converting JSON respones from API method into objects
    // note that only those properties are defind that are needed for this example

    // reponse from file methods
    class SlackFileResponse
    {
        public bool ok { get; set; }
        public String error { get; set; }
        public SlackFile file { get; set; }
    }

    // a slack file
    class SlackFile
    {
        public String id { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }        
    }

    // main method with logic
    public static void Main()
    {
        var parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        // put your token here
        parameters["token"] = "xoxp-YOUR-TOKEN";
        parameters["channels"] = "test";

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.QueryString = parameters;
        byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadFile(
                "https://slack.com/api/files.upload",
                "D:\\temp\\Stratios_down.jpg"
        );

        String responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);

        SlackFileResponse fileResponse =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackFileResponse>(responseString);
    }
}
```

About content types: Those are part of the header of a HTTP request and can be set manually in the `WebClient` object (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560769/webclient-set-headers/6560798)). However, for our case you can ignore it, because the default content types that WebClient is using for the POST request will work just fine.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535880/4379151) on how to upload files with the `WebClient` class.

Comment: You are a god among us mere mortals :) I'm kidding, but honestly your help is greatly appreciated! I hope this will not only help me but other people, too.
Thank you so much for these clear examples, all your effort and work. Your answers are clear and precice, with good examples. From that I can learn.
Again, thank you so much. And, of course, after testing your code I'll come back and upvote ;)

Comment: Now it won't upload via HttpClient. Says 'OK' in response I get. But image does not show in Slack.
My uploadMethod:

`public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(byte[] file)
 {
            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
            requestContent.Add(fileContent, "dagged", "dagged.jpg");
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_webhookUrl, requestContent);
            return response;
}`

Comment: Your WebClient-Method works fine. My HttPClient-Method works when sending a message with an attached image. But it won't work when I just want to upload any kind of file. I allways get {"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}


Okay, I figured out that the problem seems to be that I use a byte[] as content. Other people seem to have the same problem. I dont understand why, because WebClient uses a byte-array as well... I'm hella confused :D

Anyone has a good idea?

Comment: Your method has a couple of issues: 1) you are missing mandatory API parameters like `token` 2) You must not set multipart manually, its automatically set via MultipartFormDataContent()
I will add another answer with a complete async example to clarify things.

Comment: Please note that its normally better add all source updates to the question. Its hard for people to find source code in the comments. I added it for your.

Comment: Hey Erik, I guess some things have changed in 2020. I'm not sure if the codes are still valid. I have created a new token and I am getting an error like this. Can you help me ? "{\"ok\":false,\"error\":\"invalid_auth\"}"

Answer (score 4):

**Images in message**

If you want to include an image in your message (along with some text) you can do so by adding images as message attachment to a normal message send with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

For that you need a public URL of your image and that link with the `image_url` property to an attachment. That attachment can also contain text, and you can add multiple attachments to your message.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And here is how this message looks in JSON:

```
{
    "channel": "test",
    "text": "This is a message example with images in the attachment",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "game over",
            "text": "This is some text in the attachement",
            "image_url": "https://i.imgur.com/jO9N3eJ.jpg"

        }
    ]
}
```

**Uploading images**

The image URL needs to be publicly accessible on the Internet. So you need to host your image file on a public webserver or upload it to a image cloud service (e.g. imgur.com).

You can also use Slack as cloud service for your images. Here is how that works:

1. Upload to Slack: Upload your image to your Slack workspace with [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)
2. Get public URL: Get a public URL for your image file with [`files.sharedPublicURL`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL). Normally all files on Slack are private, but you can only use public URLs for message attachments.
3. Send message: Include your image as attachment in a message: Use the `permalink_public` property of your image file as value for `image_url`

**Example code**

Here is a full working example in C# for first uploading an image to Slack and then using it in a message.

Note: This example requires [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class SlackExample
{
    // classes for converting JSON respones from API method into objects
    // note that only those properties are defind that are needed for this example

    // reponse from file methods
    class SlackFileResponse
    {
        public bool ok { get; set; }
        public String error { get; set; }
        public SlackFile file { get; set; }
    }

    // a slack file
    class SlackFile
    {
        public String id { get; set; }        
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String permalink_public { get; set; }
    }

    // reponse from message methods
    class SlackMessageResponse
    {
        public bool ok { get; set; }
        public String error { get; set; }
        public String channel { get; set; }
        public String ts { get; set; }        
    }

    // a slack message attachment
    class SlackAttachment
    {
        public String fallback { get; set; }
        public String text { get; set; }
        public String image_url { get; set; }
    }

    // main method with logic
    public static void Main()
    {
        String token = "xoxp-YOUR-TOKEN";


        /////////////////////
        // Step 1: Upload file to Slack

        var parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        // put your token here
        parameters["token"] = token;

        var client1 = new WebClient();
        client1.QueryString = parameters;
        byte[] responseBytes1 = client1.UploadFile(
                "https://slack.com/api/files.upload",
                "C:\\Temp\\Stratios_down.jpg"
        );

        String responseString1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes1);

        SlackFileResponse fileResponse1 = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackFileResponse>(responseString1);

        String fileId = fileResponse1.file.id;


        /////////////////////
        // Step 2: Make file public and get the URL

        var parameters2 = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters2["token"] = token;
        parameters2["file"] = fileId;

        var client2 = new WebClient();
        byte[] responseBytes2 = client2.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/files.sharedPublicURL", "POST", parameters2);

        String responseString2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes2);

        SlackFileResponse fileResponse2 =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackFileResponse>(responseString2);

        String imageUrl = fileResponse2.file.permalink_public;


        /////////////////////
        // Step 3: Send message including freshly uploaded image as attachment

        var parameters3 = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters3["token"] = token;
        parameters3["channel"] = "test_new";        
        parameters3["text"] = "test message 2";

        // create attachment
        SlackAttachment attachment = new SlackAttachment();
        attachment.fallback = "this did not work";
        attachment.text = "this is anattachment";
        attachment.image_url = imageUrl;
        SlackAttachment[] attachments = { attachment };        
        parameters3["attachments"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attachments);

        var client3 = new WebClient();
        byte[] responseBytes3 = client3.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", "POST", parameters3);

        String responseString3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes3);

        SlackMessageResponse messageResponse =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackMessageResponse>(responseString3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another complete example for uploading a file to Slack, this time using the **async** approach with [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Note: This example requires [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SlackExample
{
    class UploadFileExample
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // classes for converting JSON respones from API method into objects
        // note that only those properties are defind that are needed for this example

        // reponse from file methods
        class SlackFileResponse
        {
            public bool ok { get; set; }
            public String error { get; set; }
            public SlackFile file { get; set; }
        }

        // a slack file
        class SlackFile
        {
            public String id { get; set; }
            public String name { get; set; }
        }

        // sends a slack message asynchronous
        // throws exception if message can not be sent
        public static async Task UploadFileAsync(string token, string path, string channels)
        {
            // we need to send a request with multipart/form-data
            var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            // add API method parameters
            multiForm.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");
            multiForm.Add(new StringContent(channels), "channels");

            // add file and directly upload it
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
            multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", Path.GetFileName(path));

            // send request to API
            var url = "https://slack.com/api/files.upload";
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, multiForm);

            // fetch response from API
            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // convert JSON response to object
            SlackFileResponse fileResponse =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackFileResponse>(responseJson);

            // throw exception if sending failed
            if (fileResponse.ok == false)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "failed to upload message: " + fileResponse.error
                );
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                        "Uploaded new file with id: " + fileResponse.file.id
                );
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // upload this file and wait for completion
            UploadFileAsync(
                "xoxp-YOUR-TOKEN",
                "C:\\temp\\Stratios_down.jpg",
                "test"
            ).Wait();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Erik, I am using an IHttpClientFactory to POST an endpoint and receive an image. Then I am using a MemoryStream to create a BitMap from the response. NOW, I need to send this BitMap as attachement to slack. Any workaround other than uploading the image to the workspace?

Comment: I have also asked it in the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442781/how-to-attach-a-bitmap-or-an-image-to-slack-message-as-attachment-c