# "no_file_data" error when trying to upload file to slack

Tags: c#, slack-api

when I try to upload any kidn of file through my SlackApp(via c# using HttpClient),
I allways get the following response:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}
```

I checked my `ByteArray` (I stream the file to an array and then try to upload) and wrote my data back into a .txt and .jpg - I tried both types of data. When i write them back they are exact copies from the original, so I guess my streaming and writing to an `ByteArray`works fine. But something is off with my upload.

I'll show you my code:
The Client and the method to upload:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;


namespace SlackApp
{
    public class SlackClient
    {
        private readonly Uri _webhookUrl;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient {};

        public SlackClient(Uri webhookUrl)
        {
            _webhookUrl = webhookUrl;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(byte[] file)
        {
            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
            requestContent.Add(fileContent, "slack", "slack.txt");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_webhookUrl, requestContent);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

the creation of the bytearray:

```
public class PostFile
{
    String path = @"C:\Users\f.held\Desktop\Held-Docs\dagged.jpg";

    public byte[] ReadImageFile()
    {            
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
        return imageData;
    }
}
```

the Main:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SlackApp
{
    class TestArea
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Task.WaitAll(IntegrateWithSlackAsync());
        }

        private static async Task IntegrateWithSlackAsync()
        {
            var webhookUrl = new Uri("https://slack.com/api/files.upload?token=xoxp-hereStandsMyToken&channel=MyChannel");  
            var slackClient = new SlackClient(webhookUrl);
            PostMessage PM = new PostMessage();
            PostFile PF = new PostFile();
            var testFile = PF.ReadImageFile();

            while (true)
            {
                var message = Console.ReadLine(); 
                FormUrlEncodedContent payload = PM.Content(message, "");
                var response = await slackClient.SendMessageAsync(payload);

                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content); //I build these two lines in here so I got the response from the method, and this is where it says "no_file_data"

                var isValid = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "valid" : "invalid";
                Console.WriteLine($"Received {isValid} response.");
                Console.WriteLine(response); //this puts out a "valid" response - oddly enough
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong here? Why isn't it taking the data?

Comment: It looks to me that you may have posted the wrong TestClass. This one does not contain any call to `UploadFile()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code:

- main(): The parameter to specify the channels is called
  `channels`, not `channel`
- UploadFile(): When you add your file content to the multipart you
  need to include the correct API parameter for the file which is `file`,
  not `slack`. And also want to include a reasonable filename (instead of `slack.txt`).

Additional comments

- UploadFile(): Its wrong to set the content type to `multipart/form-data`. The
  correct type for that content would be `image/jpeg`. However, the
  correct type seams to be detected automatically, so just remove the
  line.
- main(): The Slack API will always return OK (http 200, unless there is a network problem), so you want to also look on the `ok` and `error` properties of the JSON response instead.

Here is an update version of your code. I changed your main() method to include a call to `UploadFile()?.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SlackApp
{
    public class PostFile
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Stratios_down.jpg";

        public byte[] ReadImageFile()
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
            long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
            return imageData;
        }
    }

    public class SlackClient
    {
        private readonly Uri _webhookUrl;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient { };

        public SlackClient(Uri webhookUrl)
        {
            _webhookUrl = webhookUrl;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(byte[] file)
        {
            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);            
            requestContent.Add(fileContent, "file", "stratios.jpg");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_webhookUrl, requestContent);
            return response;
        }
    }

    class TestArea
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(IntegrateWithSlackAsync());
        }

        private static async Task IntegrateWithSlackAsync()
        {
            var webhookUrl = new Uri(
                "https://slack.com/api/files.upload?token=xoxp-MY-TOKEN&channels=test"
            );
            var slackClient = new SlackClient(webhookUrl);

            PostFile PF = new PostFile();
            var testFile = PF.ReadImageFile();

            var response = await slackClient.UploadFile(testFile);

            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

In addition I would have a couple of suggestions to improve your code.

- Instead of including the additional API parameters in the URL, I
  would send them in the POST request as recommended by the API
  documentation.
- Including the file as FileStream instead of loading it yourself into
  a ByteArray is the better approach and recommended for larger files.
- Not sure why you need an infinite loop in your main. Those are really
  bad and should be avoided.

Please also take also a look at my new [async example for uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284161/4379151) to Slack where I applied those two ideas.

Comment: Good morning, as allways very nice answer! Okay, so you say its "channels" with an 's' - but why is it "channel" on the SlackAPI-website and "channel" does work with my standard messages? 

I had, in the beginning, the parameter "file" instead of "slack" - made no difference! Also I thought this just is a name, not a real parameter... But I'm still wrong about a lot of things :)

I also had, in the beginning, no contenttype defined and then I tried `image/jpeg` instead of `multipart/form data` - all of this made no difference, it didn't work. 
I'll take a look at your approach now. Thanks

Comment: 2nd answer: I don't want to include the API paramters in the URL directly, but I don't know how to put them in the request properly. probably with `request.Add`?

I'll try the FileStream-approach instead of bytearray. And with the infinite loop... I can not even remember where that came from :D

Anyways, I'll update you here on how things are going. Thank you so far! I appreciate the help, tipps and insights.

BTW, "slack.txt" really is the name of a txt-file I created - it holds a lot information I gathered reagrding my code and the SlackApp. So, I might have bad naming habbits...

Comment: I got it working! It was the combination of `file` instead of random name because, well it really is a parameter. And it had to be `channelS` with an 's' - what the hell? I swear it says "channel" without 's' on Slack's website... how should anyone know that?

Thank you for your continuing help and efforts Erik.

Comment: Happy to help. yes, you can add the other API parameters with `request.Add` e.g. `requestContent.Add(new StringContent("xoxp-TOKEN"), "token");`

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to give some more feedback. I had a great day, I got it all working with HttpClient, without using JSON :) , I cleaned up my code, made strict, clean classes and am working on making it all accessible now :) Thanks again, man! You were of great help!

One question though. Why do you use JSON? I work with `Dicitonary<>` because I couldn't handle JSON correctly. Is there a benefit to JSON?

Comment: All API methods responses are in JSON. Also some methods require parameter input in JSON (e.g. `attachments` for messages). Since C# can not work with JSON directly you want to convert all that to some C# data structure, which can be `Dictionary<>` in some cases. Otherwise: How do you access the response attributes, e.g. `error`  in `{"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}` ??

Comment: Ah, okay... well I use this:
`             var response = await slackClient.UploadFileAsync(PM.SendFile()); 
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // with this line! it puts it out just like JSON, but of course doesn't put it in a nice object which one could deserialize... so yeah, I might have to get into JSON anyways :)
                Console.WriteLine(content);`

Comment: yes, that will work great for testing. But if you want to react programmatically to the responses (e.g. log an error message based on the response) you will need to convert it to a c# data structure. Its not that hard though. Just add the Newtonsoft JSON library.

Comment: in my case the file was correct, but I had not supplied a filename so got no_file_data. Awful error message from slack, error should be no_file_name.

Comment: Another gotcha similar to fabain-held's comment w.r.t the inconsistencies between chat and post - the type needs to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (or multipart) for snippet. Posting of messages works with "application/json" for snippets but fails with this annoying generic "no_file_data" error. I've just wasted two hours of my life figuring this out :(

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the `no_file_data` error as well.  I found out you the file needs to exist AND it needs actual content inside.  Make sure to do a size check or content length check in addition to the file exists check before uploading