# How to post Slack formated message with local attachment?

Tags: c#, image, post, slack, slack-api

Basically I want to post local image files into slack. The method only accepts URL parameters but I want to pass the path of the file. Is there a way to achieve this using formatted message ?
I had the example from this site by the way :

```
 public class SlackAttachment
    {
        public string fallback { get; set; }
...
        public string author_name { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }

    } 
public static void SendMessageToSlack()
        {

            string token= "myTokenHere";


            var sampleAttachment = new SlackAttachment[]

            {
                new SlackAttachment {

                    fallback = "this did not work",
                    text = "text here",
                    color = "0b7c1e",
                    pretext = "",
                    author_name = "myName",
                    author_icon =  @"https://i.imgur.com/02sddfQMt9p.png",
                    author_link = "",
                    title = "no title",
                    title_link = "Title link here",
                  //image_url = @"https://i.imgur.com/U9S0CDG.png",
                  // cannot replace this with 
                  //   C:\Users\Public\image.png

                    thumb_url = @"",
                    footer = "footer here",
                    footer_icon =  migrationIcon

                             },
        };

            var attachmentsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleAttachment);
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["token"] = token;
            data["channel"] = channelName;
            data["as_user"] = "true";          
            data["text"] = "";
            data["attachments"] = attachmentsJson;

            var client = new WebClient();
            var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", "POST", data);
            string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            Console.WriteLine(responseInString);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to attach a local image file to a message you need to first upload it so you get a public URL. Then you can use that URL in your message attachment.

This works with any public image service (e.g. [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/)) and you can also use any Slack workspace as host for public image files.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53265824/4379151) for details including a complete example in C#.

Comment: Thank you . I am familiar more with the first example (chat post message) 
However I get this error at run time: 
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

UploaderMessenger.SlackExample.SlackFileResponse.file.get returned null

     This is the line that generates the error:      String imageUrl = fileResponse2.file.permalink_public;

Comment: Okay is there at least a way to use the second method to only upload the image and obtain url without posting?

Comment: Sure. If you don’t provide a channel with file.upload it will not post

Comment: Thanks . While I try that do you happen to know why I get this error? see img: https://i.imgur.com/RalifhT.png

Comment: Looks to me like the response from the API in `responseString2` does not contain the property `file.permalink_public`, because the call apparently failed. It says `ok` = `false` and `error` = `not allowed`. So your token does not appear to have the required scopes to upload a file. You need either `bot`or `files.write.user`.

Comment: btw: my example code is missing some proper error handling. Normally you would check for `ok` being true before de-serializing the object.

Comment: You are right !! I didn't have access permission. I went to the following link :https://Myworkspacename.slack.com/admin/settings#public_file_urls and then enabled the option in the photo : https://i.imgur.com/om9GmsS.png

Comment: As for the error handler of course I will add them . I was just testing . Thank you so much . You are a slack hero indeed !!