# Accessing the Conversations API in c#

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have been using the recommended API; https://github.com/Inumedia/SlackAPI however there is a problem, some channels created as public and then made private don't appear either as channels or groups. Supposedly the answer to this is to use the new Conversations API that allows access to all channels/groups through the same methods. The problem is that the c# api doesn't support this. Does anyone know any other c# api that does, or are there any plans this semi-official one will support it at any time soon?

Comment: Not aware of any official libraries, but you can always call the API directly. Here is an example in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264117/how-to-upload-any-file-on-slack-via-slack-app-in-c-sharp/53265824#53265824

Comment: Thank you, yes I could try that approach if nothing else. The problem was I wanted to hook into new message alerts for the channels / groups which the .Net Api works great for. Hopefully it will be extended sometime to support Conversations too.